# Sorting dataframe with groupby with multiple condition check

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing dataframe :

```
ID  type  place   
22    A    zz         
22    A    zz         
22    B    zz         
11    C    aa         
11    C    aa
```

Expected dataframe :

```
ID  Type  place   count_of_place
22   A      zz         2
22   B      zz         1
11   C      aa         2
```

I have tried this code,

```
df['count_of_place'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['place'].transform('count')
```

Multiple appearance of place need to dropped

Answer (score 0):

Try with `value_counts`

```
out = df.value_counts().reset_index(name = 'cnt')
Out[841]: 
   ID type place  cnt
0  11    C    aa    2
1  22    A    zz    2
2  22    B    zz    1
```

Update

```
out = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),sort=False).size().reset_index(name = 'cnt')
Out[860]: 
   ID type place  cnt
0  22    A    zz    2
1  22    B    zz    1
2  11    C    aa    2
```

Comment: Appreciate ur effort..!!Actualy Their are thousands of ID, the sequence needs to same as I have shown in expected output

Comment: @Roshankumar check the update